# Pandas: how to select row with certain word

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas

How can I display only the row where the text contains the word like * AV * e.g 'AV Snow' or 'AV (Some)' or 'Me AV'

```
# Select Structural status = 'AVAILABLE' or like *AV*
value_list = ['AVAILABLE', '[AV]']
```

'[AV]' doesnt seem correct

```
# Grab DataFrame rows where column has certain values
new_df = df[df.STRUCTURALSTATUS.isin(value_list)]
new_df.shape
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is one way.

**Solution**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['AV', 'AV Snow', 'Test', 'AV (Some)',
                         'Nothing', 'Me AV', 'Available', 'NA']})

df = df[df['A'].str.contains('AV', regex=False, case=False, na=False)]
```

**Result**

```
           A
0         AV
1    AV Snow
3  AV (Some)
5      Me AV
6  Available
```

**Explanation**

- `regex=False` disables regex as it is not required for your particular task.
- `case=False` makes the search case insensitive.
- `na=False` means you won't see errors if there are unusual types in your series, e.g. non-strings.

Comment: hi, but there is this word "AV-Default" i do not want to select. So how can i select contain "AV" but not that "AV-Default"

Comment: Can you explain why not AV-Default? Is that the only one with AV you don't want?

Comment: You can use `df = df[df['A'].str.contains('AV', regex=False, case=False, na=False) & (df['A'] != 'AV-Default')]`

Comment: Thanks, just a slight modification, any word that contains like "xxx AV-Default" also to filter out, in short *AV-Default* the string contain this word.

Comment: `df = df[df['A'].str.contains('AV', regex=False, case=False, na=False) & ~(df['A'].str.contains('AV-Default', regex=False, case=False, na=False)]`

Comment: df = df[df.STRUCTURALSTATUS.str.contains('AV', regex=False, case=False, na=False) & ~
        (df.STRUCTURALSTATUS.str.contains != 'AV-DEFAULT', regex=False, case=False, na=False)]   - in valid syntax error ?

Comment: able to figure out why the syntax error on my code ?? Thanks !

Comment: `.str.contains` is a function; it's called as so: `df[col].str.contains('AV')`. Your syntax is incorrect.

Comment: df = df[df.STRUCTURALSTATUS.str.contains('AV', regex=False, case=False, na=False) & ~
        (df['STRUCTURALSTATUS'] != 'AV-DEFAULT')]
i trying to exclude "AV-DEFAULT" but now the result turn all are "AV-DEFAULT" data...

Comment: Please ask a separate question. I can't understand or read your issue over comments.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use regex patterns, you might want to use [str.contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) on your serie to filter the DataFrame. Then you can apply a list with the isin function on your result.

Example:

```
df[df.STRUCTURALSTATUS.str.contains('[AV]')]
```

Comment: hi i have this error :  AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'contains'

Comment: Sorry I forgot the str before the contains

Comment: doesnt seem work, other words also appear...not filtered out